# asp.net how to refresh gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to refresh the grid-view after insert but it's not working for me, here is my code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TimeBox" runat="server" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="CommentBox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" />
                    <asp:Button ID="insButton" runat="server" OnClick="insert" Text="Insert" />
<asp:GridView ID="MainGrid" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

*and here is the code behind:*

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // filling the grid view

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection (@"connectionString");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT tim,com FROM ten",conn);
    conn.Open();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);

    MainGrid.DataSource = ds;
    MainGrid.DataBind();  
}

protected void insert(object sender, EventArgs e) //adding the comments 
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"connectionString");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tennis (tim,com) VALUES (@tim,@com)", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tim", TimBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@com", ComBox.Text);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MainGrid.DataBind();
    conn.Close();
}
```

the insert works fine and i can see the data if I refresh the page but I am trying to refresh the grid view only without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inserting the new record, you have to re-query the database and rebind the grid (same as you do in Page_Load) with a datasource which includes the new, inserted record.

Answer (score 5):

Now that you've inserted the record, you need to rebind your datagrid using that new data. I recommend refacoring your code a little so you won't violate the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself) and extract the data call into it's own method.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        MainGrid.DataSource = GetData();
        MainGrid.DataBind();  
    }
}

protected void insert(object sender, EventArgs e) //adding the comments 
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"connectionString");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tennis (tim,com) VALUES (@tim,@com)", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tim", TimBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@com", ComBox.Text);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    MainGrid.DataSource = GetData();
    MainGrid.DataBind();
}

protected DataSet GetData()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection (@"connectionString");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT tim,com FROM ten",conn);
    conn.Open();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: If I push the insert button aren't you running GetData twice!?

Comment: There, I fixed it. Does the answer still deserve the down vote?

Comment: +1 you also write a function BindGrid for the GridView binding.

Answer (score 0):

You're not seeing the expected results because the event for your insert button is being handled after the grid has been rendered.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

As a result the data is being added to the table after you've displayed it and why doing an F5 works

Instead move the contents of page load into the `PreRender` event and all should be good